# how to find out the list of chats in which the telegram bot is a member python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, bots, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I am a telegram bot for administering channels, how can I get a list of all channels in which the bot is or is an administrator using the bot?
I use python-telegram-bot v20

So far, it turns out only to get the id of the channel in which the correspondence is directly received

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method to request that information from the [Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api). You will have to keep track manually. For this you can use [`Update.my_chat_member`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.update.html#telegram.Update.my_chat_member) as showcased [here](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/examples.html#examples-chatmemberbot).

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.