# How can i get the list of the members in a channel with a bot admin

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I have a channel telegram with a bot python using telebot in administrator. I would like to get the list of all the member of this channel. When we are administrator we can see all the member so maybe it's possible to extract them with a bot admin.

Thank you for the answer, i searched a lot but find no method for this.

I searched on the telegram api a method or function to extract the member of a channel, i expected to find a method like bot.get_chat_members(chat_id) but it doesnt exist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to find out the list of chats in which the telegram bot is a member python-telegram-bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76249407/how-to-find-out-the-list-of-chats-in-which-the-telegram-bot-is-a-member-python-t)

Comment: Please refer this [Link](https://python.plainenglish.io/get-telegram-group-members-with-python-and-telethon-11d99f3f2984) to know more about your query.